# How to design process with view and edit mode?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

I have process as shown below.

[Simple Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlzR6.png)

Here I have two task i.e., Draft and Review.(fig1)
In draft i have outcomes as "save & submit".
When i click on save the draft task should display in read only mode so for this i have created the new task as Draft view using display value pallet element(fig 2), in the draft view i have again outcome like edit, submit.
when i click on edit again it moves to draft task. The thing is here i have created the new task for draft view. As this is simple process i can create but for complex project it requires me to create one extra task.
And for the review also i have review view task.

In activiti there is save button is provided, but here if i click on save button it will be in edit mode not in the view mode. And for view mode i have different outcomes for example: edit and submit, when i click on edit outcome again the task should open in edit mode(should show outcomes save and submit). The submit always move to next task.

Please Can anyone provide me the solution to avoid creating the task as draft view and review view.

Thanks & Regards

Amruta Wandakar

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the OOTB buttons create your custom buttons "save" turns your form to read-only, and "edit" makes it writable. you find examples on creating custom form fields in activiti. if you are using activiti embedded in Alfresco you can customize your task definition (model) to include buttons and then register onClick listeners using js